# Node-horseman Unhandled rejection evaluate

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, runtime-error

I'm trying to write a basic web scraper with Node-horseman, but I'm getting some issues with CSS selectors inside the *evaluate* function. With some websites the *evaluate* function works just fine, but with others, Node throws an error.

For example:

```
var Horseman = require('node-horseman');
var horseman = new Horseman();

function getTitle() {
  var title = $('.product-name-main h1').text();
  return {title: title};
}

horseman
  .userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0')
  .open('http://shtoraoptom.ru/pokryvalo-nazsu-gul-abrikosovyj-240-260-sm')
  .evaluate(getTitle) 
  .then(function(title){
    console.log(title);
    return horseman.close();
  });
```

This code throws an error:

```
Unhandled rejection getTitle evaluate

global code evaluateJavaScript@[native code] evaluate@phantomjs://platform/webpage.js:390:39 phantomjs://code/bridge.js:121:61    at Horseman.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/node-horseman/lib/actions.js:839:38)
    at Horseman.tryCatcher (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/node-horseman/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/node-horseman/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:502:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/node-horseman/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:559:18)
    at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/node-horseman/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:596:10)
    at Async._drainQueue (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/node-horseman/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:12)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/node-horseman/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/node-horseman/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

When I try to rewrite the code another way using the same selector, it logs out the title correctly:

```
var Horseman = require('node-horseman');
var horseman = new Horseman();

function getTitle() {
  var title = $('.product-name-main h1').text();
  return {title: title};
}

horseman
  .userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0')
  .open('http://shtoraoptom.ru/pokryvalo-nazsu-gul-abrikosovyj-240-260-sm')
  .text('.product-name-main h1')
  .then(function(title){
    console.log(title);
   return horseman.close();
  });
```

What can be the reason for this type of error?

Comment: Replacing $ with jQuery inside getTitle function solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

## CAUSE

`.evaluate()` method expects client-side JavaScript function to be available in the webpage you're scraping.

The way you define `getTitle()` function in your 1st example implies it to be  created in NodeJS scope not in the scraped webpage client-side scope.

---

## POSSIBLE FIXES

> OPTION 1

You could get rid of creating `getTitle()` function but writing client-side javascript code right as an argument for `.evaluate()` method, like this:

```
.evaluate(function () { return $('.product-name h1').first().text(); })
```

(for complete solution pls. check out my GitHub repo: https://github.com/omnimind/stackOverflow/blob/master/NodeJS/Controllers/37793821.js script method called `main()`)

> OPTION 2

If you're insist on creating `getTitle()` JavaScript function then you will need to create the function in a separate JavaScript file and inject it into the webpage you're scraping by using horsemen `.injectJs(file)` like this:

```
.injectJs('<external_javascript_file>').evaluate(function () { return getTitle(); })
```

(for complete solution pls. check out my GitHub repo: https://github.com/omnimind/stackOverflow/blob/master/NodeJS/Controllers/37793821.js script method called `external()`)

---

## REMARK

The 2nd options allows you to get your code better organized especially in cases when the client-side JavaScript code you need to inject gets more complicated and robust by its size.

Comment: The statement about evaluate() a client-side function is incorrect. As the docs state `.evaluate(fn, [arg1, arg2,...])` **"Invokes fn on the page with args"**

Comment: Also, from a purely Javascript perspective, there is no reason to think that `.evalute(fn)` is any different from `evaluate(function () { })`, provided that `fn` is defined somewhere before its execution